# Как в python сделать разбиение списка и присвоение переменной

Tags: python

Как в python сделать разбиение списка и присвоение переменной? Например есть такой список

`['1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.2', '1.1.1.3', '1.1.1.4', 'qwe']`

И мне нужно привести его в такой вид -

```
ip_'1.1.1.1'
ip_'1.1.1.2'
ip_'1.1.1.3'
```

и т.д.

Не совсем то, мне нужно сделать чтобы эти все айпишники были как отдельные переменные. а не просто в каждый из них добавить слово.

Comment: А собственные мысли есть, как такое можно сделать?

Comment: Нужно присвоить переменной значение, или нужно, чтобы имя переменной включало элемент списка? Если последнее, то кавычки и точки в имени переменной не прокатят.

Comment: @Эникейщик Вот ничего не приходит в голову

Comment: приведите ваш код и напишите, что у вас не получается

Comment: @strawdog Можно конечно просто ip_1.1.1.1

Comment: @AnuarMukatov Ок. Если бы пришлось делать это просто на бумаге с карандашом, то какой был бы алгоритм? Ну и, кстати, для чего все это? Какая-то странная задача, наверняка это все не нужно делать, а можно пойти другим простым путем.

Comment: @Эникейщик У меня есть хост со скопом ip адресов, от 1 до 5, а то и больше. Вот я хочу все эти айпишники вытащить по отдельности. Они предоставлены в том виде, который я написал ранее. IP = ['1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.2', '1.1.1.3', '1.1.1.4']

Comment: Тогда непонятно, каким образом заданый вопрос связан с этой задачей. Но вообще элементы из списка берутся так: ``ip_adresa[0]`` - первый адрес в списке, ``ip_adresa[1]`` - второй адрес в списке

Comment: Все равно не ясен требуемый результат. если нужно просто привести адреса в вид ip_x.x.x.x, то можно сделать так: `scope=['1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.2', '1.1.1.3', '1.1.1.4']
ips=[('ip_'+x) for x in scope]
print(ips)`

Comment: @strawdog Не совсем то, мне нужно сделать чтобы эти все айпишники были как отдельные переменные. а не просто в каждый из них добавить слово.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно так (точки в имени переменной нужно все равно убирать):

```
scope=['1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.2', '1.1.1.3', '1.1.1.4']
vars=[]
for ip in scope:
    var = 'ip_'+ip.replace('.','_')
    globals()[var]=ip
    vars.append(var) # создаем список с именами наших новых переменных

print(vars) # выводим этот список
print(ip_1_1_1_1) # выводим переменную.
```

Вывод:

```
['ip_1_1_1_1', 'ip_1_1_1_2', 'ip_1_1_1_3', 'ip_1_1_1_4']
1.1.1.1
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @AnuarMukatov Если честно, это довольно неудобный способ работы с переменными. Проще и удобнее работать со словарём.

Answer (score 1):

Можно с помощью генератора списков еще

```
scope = ['1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.2', '1.1.1.3', '1.1.1.4']
scope = ['ip_' + i for i in scope]
```

Answer (score 1):

В таких случаях лучше создать словарь, например:

```python
scope = ['1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.2', '1.1.1.3', '1.1.1.4']
ips = {'ip_{}'.format(ip): ip for ip in scope}

print(ips['ip_1.1.1.3']) # 1.1.1.3
```